# How to get Panel to show when character lands on a specific position on game board after dice roll in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a 3D board game in Unity. I would like to move my character without having to press a key, but most importantly I would like to show a dynamic panel in canvas for whatever square the character lands on. So far I have the dice rolling and the character moving (after pressing a key) the correct amount of squares, but I am unable to figure out how to activate the panel based on the square color. Any help would be appreciated.
Here is my CharacterScript:

```
public class CharacterScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Path currentPath;
    public int squarePosition;
    public int squares;
    bool isMoving;
    public GameObject PinkSquarePanel = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("PinkSquare");
    public GameObject CyanSquarePanel = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("CyanSquare");
    public GameObject WhiteSquarePanel = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("WhiteSquare");

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape) && !isMoving)
        {
            squares = DiceNumberTextScript.diceNumber;
        }
        StartCoroutine(Move());

        if (squares == 0)
        {
            ActivateSquarePanel();
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Move()
    {
        if (isMoving)
        {
            yield break;
        }
        isMoving = true;

        while (squares > 0)
        {
            Vector3 nextPosition = currentPath.squareList[squarePosition + 1].position;
            while (MoveToNextSquare(nextPosition))
            {
                yield return null;
            }
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
            squares--;
            squarePosition++;
        }
        isMoving = false;
    }

    bool MoveToNextSquare(Vector3 goal)
    {
        return goal != (transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, goal, 4f * Time.deltaTime));
    }

    void ActivateSquarePanel()
    {
        if (squarePosition.Equals(PinkSquarePanel))
        {
            PinkSquarePanel.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().alpha = 1;
        }
        else if (squarePosition.Equals(CyanSquarePanel))
        {
            CyanSquarePanel.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().alpha = 1;
        }
        else if (squarePosition.Equals(WhiteSquarePanel))
        {
            WhiteSquarePanel.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().alpha = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my PathScript:

```
public class Path : MonoBehaviour
{
    Transform[] squareObjects;
    public List<Transform> squareList = new List<Transform>();
    GameObject[] PinkSquares = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("PinkSquare");
    PinkSquare[] pinkList = new PinkSquare[1];
    GameObject[] CyanSquares = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("CyanSquare");
    CyanSquare[] cyanList = new CyanSquare[1];
    GameObject[] WhiteSquares = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("WhiteSquare");
    WhiteSquare[] whiteList = new WhiteSquare[1];

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.black;

        FillSquares();

        for (int i = 0; i < squareList.Count; i++)
        {
            Vector3 currentPosition = squareList[i].position;
            if (i > 0)
            {
                Vector3 previousPosition = squareList[i - 1].position;
                Gizmos.DrawLine(previousPosition, currentPosition);
                if(currentPosition.Equals(PinkSquares))
                {
                    pinkList[i] = new PinkSquare();
                }
                else if (currentPosition.Equals(CyanSquares))
                {
                    cyanList[i] = new CyanSquare();
                }
                else if (currentPosition.Equals(WhiteSquares))
                {
                    whiteList[i] = new WhiteSquare();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void FillSquares()
    {
        squareList.Clear();

        squareObjects = GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();

        foreach (Transform square in squareObjects)
        {
            if (square != this.transform)
            {
                squareList.Add(square);  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue right now? I see you are moving the character until you have no more moves left based on the dice roll. After this, you are enabling a panel by using the `Canvas Group`. Are the panels not showing up? Are they in the wrong place? Are they the wrong color?  Where is the color of the square stored? What data type is it? If you paint the whole picture of the scenario and the issue it will be much easier to solve your issues. Also, I am pretty sure `OnDrawGizmos()` is an editor-only function.

Comment: What are these lines supposed to do? `currentPosition.Equals(CyanSquares)`. `currentPosition` is a type of `Vector3`. You are using a Vector3.Equals on an array of GameObjects. You will need to link your gameboard pieces and their positions to colors. There are various ways you can do this.

Comment: The panel is not showing. I have the panels under Canvas and have set their alpha to 0. I  am trying to say that if the player lands on a pink square then a pink square panel will show with options. The line currentPosition.Equals(CyanSquares) is meant to say that if the currentPosition is tagged PinkSquare, then the pink panel will show.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is in your comparisons, you are trying to use an `Equals` to compare your `currentPosition` which is a `Vector3` type to a `GameObject[]` which is an array of gameObjects. As I mentioned in my comments, this comparison will always fail as an array of gameObjects can not be equal to a vector.

Instead of using these lines, try this line:

`if(squareList[i].gameObject.tag.CompareTag("PinkSquare")`

The full snippet of if else would look like

```
if(squareList[i].gameObject.tag.CompareTag("PinkSquare")
{
    pinkList[i] = new PinkSquare();
}
else if(squareList[i].gameObject.tag.CompareTag("CyanSquare")
{
    cyanList[i] = new CyanSquare();
}
else if(squareList[i].gameObject.tag.CompareTag("WhiteSquare")
{
    whiteList[i] = new WhiteSquare();
}
```

Your `CharacterScript` is going to need to get the `gameObject` or `Transform` from the `Path` script as it is only keeping track of indexes. Your issue in this script is you are comparing an `integer` to a `GameObject` which would never be true. I would also recommend **not** using `OnDrawGizmos()` as it is an editor only script and should only be used to render editor debugging tools. The only reference to a `Gizmo` I see in the function is `Gizmos.color = Color.black;` which does nothing as you are not rendering a gizmo anywhere. I would move this code to a different function and call it from your `CharacterScript`. Have the return type be `GameObject` or `Transform` of the square you are on, so the `CharacterSCript` can check which color it lands on. Using an `Integer` nor `Vector3` to compare to a `GameObject[]` will never work.

I am not sure if there are issues elsewhere in the code, but as this comparison would always fail, none of these statements would get broken into. What this means is your panels would never have the chance to get their alpha set nor get created.